# Why was "City of Lies" pulled from theaters a month before release?

Tags: production, city-of-lies

Johnny Depp's movie **City Of Lies** was pulled from release recently, a month before premiere.

What was the rationale for such a move?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_Lies#Release) says: _"...the film was pulled from the schedule due to an ongoing lawsuit involving Depp and the film's location manager; no replacement date was announced."_

[**source**](https://deadline.com/2018/08/city-of-lies-johnny-depp-movie-pulled-release-schedule-1202441341/)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir You should put that as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 4):

[Fox news](http://www.foxnews.com/entertainment/2018/08/07/johnny-depps-movie-city-lies-pulled-from-release-schedule-month-before-premiere.html) states that,

> a crew member for “City of Lies” sued Depp alleging that the
>   55-year-old actor punched him twice.

From the [Deadline.com](https://deadline.com/2018/08/city-of-lies-johnny-depp-movie-pulled-release-schedule-1202441341/),

> City of Lies, the Brad Furman-directed crime thriller starring Johnny
>   Depp and Forest Whitaker and based on the true story behind the
>   investigation into the murder of rap star Notorious B.I.G., has been
>   pulled off its September 7 release date.

It further states,

> Global Road, which acquired the movie’s original distributor Open Road
>   last summer, has not set a new date for the pic, we’re told.
>
> The news comes less than month after the film’s location manager sued
>   Depp, accusing the actor of assault and battery on the set in April
>   2017. Gregg “Rocky” Brooks said he was repeatedly hit by Depp after being informed that filming that night in downtown L.A. was going to
>   have to wrap late. The 10-claim suit, which also names Furman and
>   producers Miriam Segal, Good Film Productions and Depp’s Infinitum
>   Nihil, seeks damages for hostile work environment, retaliation, and
>   wrongful termination among the claims.

and finally,

> The July 9-filed lawsuit has become more focused in recent days. Last
>   week, Segal and her Good Film were dropped by Brooks as defendants. We
>   hear the move was not the result of a settlement, but rather
>   discussions between the lawyers for the parties.